# Images won't show in WordPress Website

Tags: wordpress

I just uploaded my very first WordPress website and somehow i can't see the images on the website even though i can see the images in the media gallery from the dashboard http://rama.ly/

Comment: I looked in the console and you have a number of pathing errors, including some that point to localhost. Can you give us some more details about how you migrated the site to the server?

Comment: Did you do a find/replace on the database when you migrated it? See this answer I gave at WPSE: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223522/localhost-on-iphone-not-loading-images/223524#223524

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress store the full image url in database. When your website was in localhost. The url on an image was like `http://localhost/rama/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/3000-x-i-dont-know.png`

You moved your site to live domain but you have not changed `localhost` to  `rama.ly` in your database.

Now you can install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/   and replace all  `localhost` to `rama.ly` that will fix the broken images.

Also for moving wordpress sites you can use very easy to use plugins like duplicator / backupbuddy. those plugin really makes the migration easier.

Comment: thank you very much now i found the problem, but the plugin didn't fix that. now i'm trying to solve it by writing a query

Comment: Hi, The plugin is suggested here.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress    .    You can try this too if you want to do in database.

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'localhost', 'rama.ly');`